# How can a get a rectanglular portion of canvas ImageData from the cached pixeldata of the whole image?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Using `ctx.getImageData(x, y, w, h)` it is possible to retrieve the pixeldata of a rectangular portion of an image;

However I need to perform a lot of checks on various portions of the data.  Extracting the imagedata each time is expensive.  Therefore I would like to cache the whole canvas imagedata, and have a function return the pixels of a given rectangle within that cached data.

In other words, if I have retrieved the imagedata of the **whole** canvas in advance and cached it to a variable, how can I then extract a rectangular portion of the pixeldata from this cache?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to parse a region of a larger bitmap array `[rx, ry, rwidth, rheight]`,:

```
for(var y = ry; ry < (ry + rheight); y++) {
    for(var x = rx; x < (rx + rwidth); x++) {

        var pos = (y * width + x) * 4;  /// for byte arrays
        var pos =  y * width + x;       /// for Uint32 arrays
    }
}
```

`pos` being the position in the array. If you don't need to check individual components (or you can use a static 32-bit value for comparison) I would recommend you to use an Uint32Array view on the buffer which is much faster than iterating a byte array.

However, to *extract* the region is probably slower than using `getImageData()` as you would need to use JS to iterate as above to get the region, then iterate again parsing the data using JS.